# grep - combining postive and negative expressions

Tags: grep

I have come across examples of combining multiple search expressions like

```
grep -e 'phrase1|phrase2|phrase3'
```

but I am struggling with combining both positive and negative expressions in a search. I am looking to use grep to extract a list of file names from a directory where the file:

- does not contain the text '[downloadedimages]'
- AND
- contains the text '[images]'

I tried the following but it throws a syntax error [-e: command not found]

```
grep -v -e '"\[downloadedimages\]"' | -e '"\[images\]"' -l /path/to/files
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep 'images' /path/to/files | grep -v 'downloadedimages'`

Comment: I get an error message  `grep: /path/to/files: Is a directory`

Comment: then you should write path with returns files, eg:
`grep 'images' /path/to/files/* | grep -v 'downloadedimages'`